# Handle Non-UTF-8 Characters in Byte Array

Tags: c#, utf-8

I have an array of bytes which contains some characters that are **not UTF-8**. These characters cannot be deserialized using UTF-8 encoding. So, my question is, how can I handle these characters and make the string readable in whatever language it is.

For example, if I have an array:

```
byte[] b = myArrayWithNonUTF8Characters;
```

And I try to deserialize the array with:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyObject));

MyObject objResponse = (MyObject)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(b));
```

Then I get an error that the array **contains invalid UTF8 bytes**.

Any way to make this work?

**PS:** Please, do not give me this answer: `string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b, 0, b.Length);` It will only return symbols replacing the non-UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Well what encoding *is* the text in? Where did this data come from? Are you happy to use an alternative JSON library, e.g. Json.NET?

Comment: @JonSkeet The array comes from a web-service. `byte[] b = _client.UploadValues(address, "POST", nvc);` And I don't know its encoding. Any way I can find that out?

Comment: The HTTP response should include that in the Content-Encoding header. To find that out in code, you'll probably need to use WebRequest/WebResponse or HttpClient instead of WebClient.

Comment: You have to convert it with the correct encoding. Trying to guess the encoding leads to strange results.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am not sure if I can use HTTPClient. Do you know any other workaround?

Comment: Ideally, make the server return utf-8... We don't really have much context for what's possible at the moment.

Comment: The only way to make it readable is to know which bytes are in which character set and encoding. If you don't have that then you've lost data. A string without this metadata—or at least a known context—is gibberish.

Comment: @JonSkeet The server is actually returning content in UTF-8, but there are some characters in form of black rhombus with an interrogation sign inside which can not be deserialized. Remember the error is thrown at `jsonSerializer.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(b))`.

Comment: @JoeAlmore: Well that suggests it's not proper UTF-8, or at least invalid JSON. It would really help if you could provide an example of the binary data (the raw bytes) being returned... ideally just a short one including some invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of UTF is that it encodes characters in most languages; so you can have Greek and Japanese in the same character stream.

Without UTF, your entire stream (or in your case an array) must be in a single language defined by a Code Page.  Each character is represented by an ASCII byte but the actual character is determined by the Code Page (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page for more details).

For example if your text was written in Greek you might use Code Page 111:

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(111)
```

In short, you need to know what language the ASCII text was written in.